# Существует ли инструментарий для создания анимации в material design?

Tags: android, material-design

В описании концепции `material design` есть обзорное видео `motion`:

[MaterialMotionHero Spec 0505](https://youtu.be/HIu_iKx5rCo)

Наверняка Google написали инструментарий, как обычно. Будь я на их месте, я бы вообще создал отдельную программу, по примеру `JavaFX Scene Builder` для `JavaFX`. Но может быть, такой инструментарий существует? Приложение или стандартные библиотеки, написанные специально для `material design`?

Comment: О чем вы спрашиваете, какая это может быть программа и что и как она должна делать? Есть классы API андроид, [реализующие анимацию](http://www.fandroid.info/urok-6-ustanovka-polzovatelskih-animatsij-v-material-design/):`Animation`, `ObjectAnimator`, `ViewAnimationUtils`, `Transition` и другие - вот вам инструменты для анимаций

Comment: Спасибо! Но лучше бы Вы это написали в отдельном ответе, чтобы я мог принять Ваш ответ.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов добавил ссылки на русскоязычные ресурсы и офф доки в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инструментов нет - остается писать самим, либо использовать готовое: [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20animations&type=), [AndroidArsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/6?category=1)

Если надумаете писать сами, можете посмотреть исходники вот этой библиотеки: [Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)  - скрины анимаций ниже, информация на русском языке: [Animation и Transition](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/), [Анимация преобразований](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/tweenanimation.php), [Векторная анимация в приложениях android](http://www.fandroid.info/vektornaya-animatsiya-v-prilozheniyah-android-animated-vector-drawable/), [Building Apps with Graphics & Animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html), [Установка пользовательских анимаций в Material Design](http://www.fandroid.info/urok-6-ustanovka-polzovatelskih-animatsij-v-material-design/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ДОБАВЛЕНО: Также, [пользовательскую анимацию можно установить](http://www.fandroid.info/urok-6-ustanovka-polzovatelskih-animatsij-v-material-design/) при помощи библиотек: `Animation`, `ObjectAnimator`, `ViewAnimationUtils`, `Transition`.

Comment: В [моем комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673934/%d0%a1%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-material-design#comment982023_673934) ссылка на достаточно полный гайд по многим типам анимации сразу в применении к Material-стилю, можете ее тоже добавить, чтобы не потерялась

Comment: @pavlofff добавил - чем больше информации, тем лучше!